# Magento (sales igniter) site - Not responsive

Tags: database

I had a new theme installed via FTP. It did not respond so the theme was removed via FTP.  It looks like some of the master Magento files were also deleted at this time and now the only in to anything is via C-Panel.  Please see below as this is what comes up for both the website and the admin login.  Any one know step by step how to retrieve and fix this.

Thanks in advance for any help..

```
Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/celebrat/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 51

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/celebrat/public_html/app/code/local:/home/celebrat/public_html/app/code/community:/home/celebrat/public_html/app/code/core:/home/celebrat/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lsws/lsphp55/lib/php') in /home/celebrat/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 51

Warning: include(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/celebrat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68

Warning: include(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/celebrat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/celebrat/public_html/app/code/local:/home/celebrat/public_html/app/code/community:/home/celebrat/public_html/app/code/core:/home/celebrat/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lsws/lsphp55/lib/php') in /home/celebrat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68

Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /home/celebrat/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 5
```

Answer (score 0):

clearly, your Varien_Autoload file is deleted and there could other deleted files too. I am going to assume that you don't have a backup of your store.

First, i suggest to check with your host if they can revert your Magento installation to a previous state, you might be able to revert it to a point just before you installed the theme.

If your host can't do that then you might have to manually replace the core files. This can be very messy based on what and how much files are deleted. If it's just core files and no custom files, it will be slightly easier. Unfortunately, if custom files are deleted and you don't have to copies of them then you will have to create them again.

If its just core files that are deleted(assuming they were not directly customized before they were deleted) you can download a new installation of the Magento version you have and replace the necessary file starting with Varien_Autoload but this can be hectic as magento has many files, so if too many core files are deleted it might be easier to migrate your store to a fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have never really had to much success with managing a site via ftp. The quickest way to restore default files is to first confirm your magento version by looking in the *app/Mage.php*, there is a function getVersion which will give you a good idea of the version that you are using. With this information download a clean version from Magento's archive page. With this you can copy across all files across to your site.

This is a bit of a risky approach and firstly, any applied patches could be removed, to mitigate this I would apply all patches locally before uploading files. Secondly files like you email templates and language  files could be overwritten, which also can be mitigated if you remove these files from you local copy before copying over. Lastly which as a Magento developer I hope is not the case, but if there are changes made to lib files these will be overwritten.

To help prevent these kind of issue in the future I would strongly recommend that you start implementing some kind of version control for your site. Even if you just keep a local git repository on your machine, anything to help track changes and make rolling back easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your input it is very much appreciated..  I am going to try to down load a new installation of Magento since this is a brand new site and no custom files had been introduced to it as of yet. The first thing we did was install new theme and obviously it was not done correctly.  Do either of you know if there have been problems with Glory-Magento Theme in the past.